# Django CSRF verification failed in django 3.1, used to work in django 1.x

Tags: django, csrf-token

I'm resurrecting and old site which worked using django 1.x.  I am running django 3.1.2 now. I converted to python 3 from 2.7.  I have 3 forms that post to the site.  They all work when running django server on the local machine.  But when I test from another machine on my network they give CSFR cookie not sent

the form:

```
<form action="/blog/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<ul><li><label for="id_title">Title:</label> <input type="text" name="title" maxlength="50" required id="id_title"></li>
<li><label for="id_file">File:</label> <input type="file" name="file" required id="id_file"></li></ul>
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="eYpdkogXUvof1IqJzgMvJcEGMBpXbvoNLTZNfEjz6aY7WebxbxsvId3nPmT7S4PF">
   <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

The view:

```
219 def handle_uploaded_file(f, to_filename):                                       
220     print("In handle_uploaded_file")                                            
221     with open(f'uploads/{to_filename}', 'wb+') as destination:                  
222         for chunk in f.chunks():                                                
223             destination.write(chunk)                                            
224     print(f"wrote {to_filename}")                                               
225                                                                                 
226                                                                                 
227 def upload_file(request):                                                       
228     print("in upload_file")                                                     
229     if request.method == 'POST':                                                
230         print("request.method == 'POST'")                                       
231         form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)                      
232         if form.is_valid():                                                     
233             print("form is valid")                                              
234             print(request)                                                      
235             handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'], request.POST['title'])  
236             return HttpResponseRedirect('upload')                               
237     else:                                                                       
238         print("in upload_file else clause")                                     
239         form = UploadFileForm()                                                 
240     return render(request, 'blog_app/upload_form.html', {'form': form})
```

The template:

```
  1 {% extends 'base.html' %}
  2     {% block head %}
  3         <title>joelgoldsick.com - {{entry.title}}</title>
  4     {% endblock %}
  5     {% block content %}
  6 
  7     <form action="{% url 'upload_file' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  8         {% csrf_token %}
  9         <ul>{{ form.as_ul }}</ul>{% csrf_token %}
 10    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
 11 </form>
 12     {% endblock %}
```

I suspect that there are new settings in settings.py  but I haven't been able find an answer.

Comment: Your template doesn't seem to match the rendered HTML. `{% csrf_token %}` is stated twice in the template code, but the HTML code block only has 1 csrf input. I don't think it's related to your issue, but perhaps you can double-check for the sake of clarity?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your response with an explanation for why you believe it answers the OP's question? Like providing a source for the information or explaining what the code does?

Comment: I just added the template.  The csrf_token is in it.